# Whatever happened to http_send_file in PHP's pecl_http module?

Tags: php, http, range

After spending well over a day trying to get the pecl_http 2.x extension to load on my server (which was no easy task on windows!), I finally succeeded in loading the extension and confirming that it is loaded.

Unfortunately, it appears my efforts are in vain. While there is no mention of this in documentation anywhere, **it looks like http_send_file() and numerous other useful related functions have been long removed from pecl_http**.

As the old php documentation states, http_send_file() is useful for having php automatically handle HTTP Range requests and partial file and data downloads by looking at the HTTP Range headers. http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/function.http-send-file.php

My question is, does anyone know if there is a modern equivalent to this function built into php or one of its extensions? The "modern" pecl_http 2.x documentation is virtually non-existent and what little there is indicates that http_send_file (and numerous other related functions including http_send_data, http_send_stream, http_throttle, http_send_content_type and http_send_content_disposition) no longer exist and have no equivalent modern replacements.

Comment: I've never used this module, but `http_throttle` should be replaceable with [`http\Env\Response::setThrottleRate`](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Env/Response/setThrottleRate), although see the warning. `http_send_content_type` is [`http\Env\Response::setContentType`](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Env/Response/setContentType) and `http_send_content_disposition` is [`http\Env\Response::setContentDisposition`](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Env/Response/setContentDisposition). I don't know if the `http_send_*` has an direct equivalents, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I researched this a bit more and I also found an implementation of http-send-file along with some of the other obsoleted functions on git which appear to be equivalent here: https://github.com/diversen/http-send-file

The other choice I found, as far as handling http ranges is to delegate it to Apache and let it handle the range headers, which bypasses PHP handling the range headers and therefore doesn't allow customization, by installing the X-Sendfile module into Apache and responding with the `header('X-Sendfile: '.$output);` where $output is the path to the requested file the server is responding with.

As a side note, there is a second issue which is on the browser side. I found that Chrome, and other browsers like Opera, specify the range header as the *entire* file with `Range: bytes=0-` even when only a small chunk of it is required for retrieving meta information or a still-frame from a video requested through the HTML 5 player for example. This places an unnecessary burden on the server to load the entire media file and send it back to the browser when it is totally unnecessary. I am certain the Youtube video player doesn't work this way!